# cppcheck null pointer dereference, but it can actually become null

Tags: c, null-pointer, cppcheck

I have a function that can return a pointer to a structure or NULL (Example to explain return possibilities of *get_my_struct_from_[X]* functions):

```
struct my_struct *my_function(my_struct i) {
    if (i.value < 5) return i;
    else return NULL;
}
```

In the main program I'm calling this function multiple times and then checking if the value is NULL or not:

```
struct my_struct *q;
q = get_my_struct_from_A();
if (q == NULL) {
    // display an error message and exit
}

q = get_my_struct_from_B();
if (q == NULL) {
    // display an error message and exit
}
```

CppCheck is telling me that the if statements are redundant or there is a possible null pointer dereference.

**Questions:**

1. Why does CppCheck gives me these messages?
2. How to correctly check the return value of the function so I don't get this message

**EDIT:**

Forgot to mention that the my_function is an example for how the two get functions behave.

The get_my_struct_from_A and get_my_struct_from_B have different internal logic, but the output data types are the same as show in my_function. I have a lot of get_my_struct_from_X functions that I call and check the return values. So creating a new structure for each get is not an option, I don't consider that a good, because of the large amount of variables used for the same purpose.

Writing `q == null` or `!q` returns the same messages from cppcheck which is normal I think.

Comment: There is a problem in `my_function`: the return type is `struct my_struct *` (a pointer) but you return an `int` (`i`).

Comment: Before using cppcheck your code shopuld compile without warnings. If you didn't get a warning, compile with `-Wall`

Comment: Is `my_function` the same as `get_my_struct_from_A`?

Answer (score 1):

Your function is supposed to return `struct my_struct *` and what did you return when `i.value` less than 5? `struct my_struct`.

Also if you declared the function like this you should pass a parameter which you didn't.

```
struct my_struct *my_function(struct my_struct* i) {
    if (i->value < 5) return i;
    else return NULL;
}
```

You will call it like this

```
struct my_struct a;
...
struct my_struct *q = my_function(&a);
if( !q ){
   // it returned NULL
}
```

---

if what you showed is what you did then there are problems/suggestions which are summarized below.

- <sub>P</sub> Returning wrong type from the method.
- <sub>P</sub> If `get_my_struct_from_A` is same as `my_function` in your original code  then you are not passing the parameter which you should.
- <sub>S</sub> This kind of small checkings can be done much more easily by using a function which returns true or false based the structure passed.

  `bool my_function(struct my_struct ms);`

Comment: The main issue here is how this code could compile cleanly in the first place, before static analysis.

Comment: @Lundin.: Yes I guess OP is not posting the exact code or OP changed it while posting here. Otherwise it throws me error. That's why I explicitly mentioned the points which will make OP write a compilable code.

Comment: @coderredoc I am not posting the exact code, I don't want a code response I want an explanation on why I'm having this problem. Added some more explanation to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct my_struct *my_function(my_struct i) {
    if (i.value < 5) return i;
```

This isn't valid C (or C++) code. Your compiler is broken or incorrectly configured.

You return an integer but the function returns a pointer. The C standard is clear, C11 6.8.6.4:

> If the expression has a
>   type different from the return type of the function in which it appears, the value is
>   converted as if by assignment to an object having the return type of the function.

Meaning that the code is equivalent to `struct my_struct* tmp = i;`. This can be regarded as what the C language calls "simple assignment". The rule of simple assignment C11 6.5.16.1 says that if the left operand of an assignment is a pointer, then the right operand cannot be an integer.

Thus your compiler *must* yield a diagnostic message for this code. If not, something is wrong with it.